# Error en Angular al mostrar imágenes

Tags: angular

Creando una aplicación **Angular mediante un servicio REST**, tengo un componente que muestra un listado de categorías. El problema que tengo es el siguiente:

> GET http://Angular/EDV/src/assets/Categoria/Futbol.png
>
> net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

No me muestra las imágenes y me aparece este error. Sin embargo, los demás datos del servicio me los muestra correctamente.

¿A qué es debido este error? ¿Y cómo lo puedo solucionar?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: yo opino que lo mejor paa traer una imagen desde un backend es desde su url

Comment: Esa "url" te trae el servicio?

Comment: El problema está en que previamente solucioné un error de url desconocida. Para hacer esto, añadí la ruta de http:// y seguidamente el error que acabo de mencionar

Answer (score 0):

Eso solo pasa en chrome:

- borra la cache y las cookies que existan del sitio

y si el problema persiste prueba:

- en apagar el modem y encenderlo

y si aun asi no funciona

- usa un antivirus actualizado y pasaselo a tu pc